# Почему промис не хочет обработать ошибку?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Есть часть кода:

```
const options   = {};

options.maxFileSize = 15728640;

const _downloadFile = (insalesid, url) => {
  const downloadOptions = {
    directory: './rest/uploads',
    filename: 'csv-' + insalesid + '.csv'
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    download(url, downloadOptions, function(err){
      if (err) reject('Ошибка при загрузке файла');

      const filePath = downloadOptions.directory + '/' + downloadOptions.filename;

      fs.stat(filePath, (err, stats) => {
        if (err) { 
          reject('Файл не найден');
          return;
        };
        if (stats.size > options.maxFileSize) { 
          _deleteFile(filePath);
          reject('Слишком большой размер файла');
        } else {
          resolve(downloadOptions.directory + '/' + downloadOptions.filename);
        }
      });

    });
  });
};


function getFileArr(user, link, callback){
  _downloadFile(user.id, link)
    .then((result) => {
      callback({ data: _parseCsvFile(result) });
    }, (err) => {
      callback({error: err});
    });
};
```

Когда промис натыкается на какую-нибудь ошибку (например слишком большой размер файла) - выдаёт следующие ошибки:

```
    (node:14132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at F:\job\IS-products-autoupdate\api\rest\controllers\settingsController.js:19:27
    at _downloadFile.then (F:\job\IS-products-autoupdate\api\rest\models\File.js:56:7)
    at <anonymous>
(node:14132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14132) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка происходит внутри then в функции callback. Переданный обработчик ошибки самого промиса ее не перехватывает. Ваш случай иллюстрирует разницу между такой записью:

```
_downloadFile(user.id, link)
    .then((result) => {
      callback({ data: _parseCsvFile(result) });
    }, (err) => {
      callback({error: err});
    });
```

и такой:

```
_downloadFile(user.id, link)
    .then((result) => {
      callback({ data: _parseCsvFile(result) });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      callback({error: err});
    });
```

во втором случае в catch будут попадать ошибки в том числе произошедшие внутри then.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Во втором случае отлавливает?

Comment: хмм, к сожалению нет , осталась та же ошибка

Comment: Попробуйте пооборачивать внутри Promise блоки кода в try/catch, где в catch будете делать reject, чтобы найти, где валится неотловленная ошибка. Ну и убедиетсь, что ничего не падает внутри callback внутри catch.